# Excel files on a Samba network drive don't open

Tags: excel, windows, windows-server-2019

I have a Microsoft Server 2019 Standard with MS Office installed. I also have a Linux server that shares each user's `~/windows/` directory through Samba with their Windows account when they're logged in. The rights to the folder are always set to `777` and are owned by the user and the group `users`, to which the user belongs.

However, when they open a .xslx file located in the said directory, the following error appears:

> "Sorry, we couldn't find \AppData\Local\Microsoft\INetCache\Content.MSO\111191F2.xlsx. It
> is possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

Opening up the location reveals that the file is indeed there, which hints at some problems with privileges. Opening the file on the network drive as Administrator works, which again hints at problems with privileges, but I haven't been able to debug this.

I did no Active Directory setup, the disk is connected using `net use` (with a user's password) in the following way:

```
net use S: \\<address>\<user> <password>
```

As for the Samba config, here is the relevant part:

```
[homes]
  browseable = no
  path = /home/%S/windows
  read only = no
  valid users = %S
```

Saving the file locally and opening it after works without any problems.

Editing a simple text file in Notepad works without any issues. Samba logs the following (it logs much more, but this should hopefully be the relevant part):

```
[2021/11/01 11:27:49.692907,  3] ../source3/smbd/dir.c:1225(smbd_dirptr_get_entry)
  smbd_dirptr_get_entry mask=[*] found test.txt fname=test.txt (test.txt)
[2021/11/01 11:27:49.692966,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3195(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[5] status[STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_query_directory.c:158
[2021/11/01 11:27:49.694329,  2] ../source3/smbd/open.c:1447(open_file)
  tom opened file test.txt read=Yes write=No (numopen=4)
[2021/11/01 11:27:49.694999,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3195(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_getinfo.c:159
[2021/11/01 11:27:49.696187,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_read.c:421(smb2_read_complete)
  smbd_smb2_read: fnum 2027028822, file test.txt, length=24 offset=0 read=24
```

Running `accesschk.exe -ld S:` (by the problem user) yields the following:

```
S:\
  DESCRIPTOR FLAGS:
      [SE_DACL_PRESENT]
      [SE_DACL_PROTECTED]
      [SE_SELF_RELATIVE]
  OWNER: S-1-5-21-2603346316-3644132649-3033319823-1025
  [0] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: S-1-5-21-2603346316-3644132649-3033319823-1025
          [OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE]
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
    FILE_ALL_ACCESS
  [1] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: S-1-22-2-1000
          [OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE]
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
    FILE_ALL_ACCESS
  [2] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: Everyone
          [OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE]
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
    FILE_ALL_ACCESS
  [3] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: S-1-22-2-1000
    FILE_ALL_ACCESS
  [4] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: S-1-5-21-2603346316-3644132649-3033319823-1025
    FILE_ALL_ACCESS
  [5] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: CREATOR OWNER
          [OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE]
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
          [INHERIT_ONLY_ACE]
    FILE_ALL_ACCESS
  [6] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: CREATOR GROUP
          [OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE]
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
          [INHERIT_ONLY_ACE]
    FILE_ALL_ACCESS
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: In order to help you  we would need to know if you have AD in place; the valid portion of your `smb.conf`.  What is the user under which you share the user's directory?  For next time -  this question is better suited for superuser.

Comment: I edited the answer to (hopefully) contain this information.

Comment: This is much better.  Did you try writing a simple text file, editing it and saving it (via e.g. notepad)?  Did it work for you?  What does the smbd.log file say (don't forget to raise your logging level)?  What are the rights on the `~/windows/` directory?  Is that user part of any group?

Comment: I again edited the question to include this information.

Comment: Thanks. Could you post a result of Sysinternals (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/accesschk) `accesschk.exe -ld \\<address>\<user>`? (or S:)

Comment: I again did so.

Comment: You maybe suffering from the `SYNCHRONIZE bit` issue.  Could you try to set it, if it helps?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/access-denied-access-smb-file-share

Comment: Running the command described in the linked page (changing via `icacls`) on the entire share changes nothing about the permissions. However, a newly created folder on the share contains the synchronized bit and the issue still persists when opening an Excel file in the folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238791/discussion-between-tukan-and-tomas-slama).

Comment: Go to control panel, set to small icons, go to sync center. Check the offline files is disabled.
In control panel, go internet options, security tab, trusted sites – try listing your samba server as a trusted site. The directory your error comes from is where Office caches things – it may be treating your file as from as unsafe from an insecure zone. I tried replicating your setup but with windows 10 - everything worked, but my samba server is on a local lan, trusted by default.

Comment: Tried it, sadly without success.

Answer (score 0):

```
Go to File -> Options -> Trust Center -> click on Trust Center Settings -> Trusted Locations -> select "Allow Trusted Locations on my network(not recommended"
```

Then Click on "File Block Settings" under Trust Center,

Uncheck the following or others that pertain to your excel version.

```
"Excel 4 Workbooks”

"Excel 4 Worksheets”

"Excel 3 Worksheets”

"Excel 2 Worksheets”

"Excel 4 Macrosheets and Add-in files"

"Excel 3 Macrosheets and Add-in files"

"Excel 2 Macrosheets and Add-in files"
```

Click Ok.

Close all your excel files and try to open that excel file from the network share.

Comment: `Allow Trusted Locations on my network` were already checked, nothing to do there. As for the File Block Settings, unchecking sadly didn't seem to work (same error).

Answer (score 0):

I just remembered that you are probably missing samba user map file, which maps windows user to *nix user.

In the `[global]` section you need to add

```
[global]
user map = /<path>/mapusers.txt
```

The details can be found at [man pages](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#USERNAMEMAP).

In the text file `mapusers.txt` you need to have one line per mapping.

In your case it would be all windows users are mapped to one linux user or group:

`linux_user = windows_user`

or

`@linux_group = @windows_group`